On the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank of global Galois groups
Let $K$ be a number field and let $p$ be a prime number. Let $S_p$ denote the set of all primes of $K$ above $p$. If $S$ is finite set of primes of $K$, then we denote by $G_S$ the Galois group of maximal pro-$p$ extension of $K$ unramified outside $S$. Let $G_S^{\text{ab}}$ denote the abelianization of $G_S$. I'm interested in the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}G_S^{\text{ab}}$ of the group $G_S^{\text{ab}}$. If $S\cap S_p=\emptyset$, then $G_S^{\text{ab}}$ is finite and hence $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}G_S^{\text{ab}}=0$; If $S\supset  S_p$, then $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}G_S^{\text{ab}} \geq r_2+1$ where $(r_1,r_2)$ is the signature of $K$. Moreover, Leopold's conjecture claims the equality.
Now assume that $S\cap S_p\neq \emptyset$ and $S_p\nsubseteq S$. What can we say about $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}G_S^{\text{ab}} $? For example, it's clear that $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}G_S^{\text{ab}}\leq r_2+1 $ assuming Leopold's conjecture. Can we make a reasonable prediction of this value? Any references would be highly appreciated.

It's clear that in the "generic" case the rank is $\max( | S \cap S_p| - (r_1+r_2-1),0)$. Probably this will happen unless the Galois orbit structure forces it to be larger, but I'm not sure exactly how to describe that cleanly.

The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2451 makes a conjecture ("the strong Leopoldt conjecture") which implies that this number can be computed purely "group theoretically" in terms of the Galois group $G$ (of the Galois closure), the conjugacy class of complex conjugation $c$, and the set $S$. Unsurprisingly the prediction is "as small as possible subject to the Group theoretic constraints", but it is not so clear how to compute this, even for a degree $24$ extension with Galois group $S_4$. Naturally CM subfields of $K$ show that the "generic" case is not correct in general.

@WillSawin For example, if $p$ splits completely in $K$ and $|S\cap S_p|=r_1+r_2-1$, then how to prove $\operatorname{rank}{\mathbb{Z}{p}}G_S^{\text{ab}} =0$ (in most cases)?

Clearly @WillSawin is just making a prediction since this equality trivially implies Leopoldt's conjecture which you can't prove generically. For  something one can prove, assume $K/\mathbf{Q}$ is abelian. If $K$ is real then the answer is zero. If $K$ is complex of degree $2n$, suppose $p$ splits completely. Then the primes above $p$ are partitioned into $n$ pairs which are exchanged by complex conjugation. Now if $S$ contains exactly $0 \le m < n$ of these pairs then the rank is provably exactly $m$. You see "non-generic" behavior here as soon as soon as $2n \ge 6$.

You're unlikely to get an answer to the question better than "just look in that paper".
